# Symfony Diem alternatives?

Tags: symfony, diem-cms

I'm looking for an alternative to Diem, based on Symfony. Do you guys know anything? We're building an CRM and we wanted to make things faster and easier, including UI and general system logic.

Comment: I was looking for a package of building blocks, common to most CRUD-oriented systems, allowing us to focus on the business logic and less on "how to list those customers in a nice table with AJAX filters/pagination/etc".

Comment: Requests for tools or other software are off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You should try Sf2 with AdminBundle (and others).
http://symfony2bundles.org/

Otherwise there are - always - Apostrophe Now and Sympal.

Comment: these are more oriented towards content management, not usefulness for different applications

Comment: I agree but you can fork them to make your CRM. It's a bit more complicated  (Diem is perhaps still the best choice!). I rest on the idea of ​​Symfony2 and bundles as [CMF](http://cmf.symfony.com/) is not finalized.

Comment: I was looking for a package of building blocks, common to most CRUD-oriented systems, allowing us to focus on the business logic and less on "how to list those customers in a nice table with AJAX filters/pagination/etc".

Comment: Diem is built for that and it's the one.
But by combining Symfony2 bundles you can achieve the same result with a better mastery of the code.